# Conflict between double click and sorting in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some problem with double click and sorting in datagrid.

When I double clicked on the header with enabled row my sorting is broke. I attempted filtering double click, but I have failure, this is a code, but dependencyObject is not always has name "DataGridHeaderBorder", and I dont know why?

```
private void dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    if (dependencyObject.DependencyObjectType.Name != "DataGridHeaderBorder")
    {
        Edit_Task_MenuItem(sender, (RoutedEventArgs)e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`e.OriginalSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) is the very first object on which the [routed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) is fired, it may be the `TextBlock` containing the header text or any other element inside the header. The `sender` on the other hand would be the object on which the event handler is attached.

Comment: Thank you, I decide doing like this, but I have a DataGridCheckBoxColumn in my cell. When I click double on datagrid border I capture Border not TextBlock. When I click double on cell with DataGridCheckBoxColumn I capture Border too. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Aleksey: I don't quite get what you try to do so i do not know. Also you only asked about *why* it does not behave like you expected which i answered i think...